# c# comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm working on windows form, and on that form i have a comboBox that attached to a dataBase, and several empty textBoxes that dosen't attached to anything...
now what i want is this:
when i choose a value from the comboBox then the empty textBoxes will fill with data from the dataBase...
for example, if the comboBox attached to a "person" table to the "ID" column, then when i choose an ID number from the comboBox then the empty textBoxes will fill with that same person data, like age,birthDate,height exc...

i know that i'm suppose to use the function "SelectedIndexChanged", but how?
if someone can help me or even post a similer example it will help alot
thanks!

Comment: I suggest you search the web for winforms databinding tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing?

```
    private void comboName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String lookupName = comboName.SelectedText;

        String id = String.Empty;
        Int32 age = 0;
        PullDataFromDatabase(lookupName, ref id, ref age);

        textID.Text = id;
        textAge.Text = age.ToString();
    }
```